# Change the font of the page by direct drag and dropping woff file on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, frontend

i need to create a particular react application that should be able to do 2 things:

1. permits drag&drop of a woff file
2. use the woff file as a font for the page

i disassembly it in 3 main tasks, the first task is create a react page that is able to intercept drop of the file, second transfer that file to a flask server and third use the server flask as a self hosted fonts server.
But i realize that it isn't so easy, so there is a simplest way to archive the same goal ? this is not for production purpose but only for a demostration.
indeed is this a good path to archive my goal and create a dynamic page that is able to change the font based on the one inserted by the user?

Answer (score 0):

I would try posting this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) Its another Stack Exchange site but focused more on best practices and discussion.